# How to find an IT job in Australia as an offshore applicant with strong experience and expertise?

Tags: job-search, australia, visa

I am a professional with 10+ years' work experience in software engineering and data industry based in China, and right now I'd like to find opportunities in Australia (all regions) for better living environment.

I believe my experience is quite evidently strong as I've authored popular open-source projects on GitHub (~10k stars), so I've attempted to submit job applications to Australian companies on recruitment websites like Indeed, LinkedIn. However, I've got no luck here as it seems the work permit is require by all employers, so not even an interview has been received so far.

Therefore I am wondering what is the best practice to find jobs in Australia from offshore, or what channels except for sending CVs I could try.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to work remotely from China for companies located in Australia ?

Comment: If you're looking to move look into the 482 and 189 visa subclasses. There are others but I'd start with those. It's going to be tough getting a job just sending out applications. Try reaching out to your professional network to see if anyone has Australian contacts. A good Oz-based headhunter can help, too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a visa requirement to work in Australia, and it's a government requirement.

The Visa that is most likely to be useful to you is the 482 visa. You should try searching for that.

Otherwise, there is a potential pathway to be employed by a MNC and then look to transition across.

Doing my own quick searches, it does indeed appear tough.

I highly recommend you engage with a local emigration agent in China who can best advise the way forward.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said need a 482 visa most likely. This means that you need to find an organisation that will sponsor you.

Answer (score 0):

## Get a student visa.

Enroll at an Australian university as an international student with a student visa. This will allow you to work for 20 hours a week. Use this to find a part-time job; many Australian companies will be open to flexible working arrangements, finding a company that is open to you working for 2.5 days per week might be possible.

Then, once you finish your degree, your employer might be willing to help you with your visa to enable you to transition to full-time work.

Of course, the downside to this is that you'll need to spend tens of thousands of dollars a year paying international student fees for the university you're attending, and you will need to dedicate significant time to your studies.

Comment: "*I am a professional with 10+ years' work experience *". Student visa, really ?!

Comment: @OldPadawan Sure. It'll probably be a lot easier to enroll in a Master's Degree then find a job once you're already in Australia.

Comment: Well, that means investing a lot of time and money whilst loosing a lot of income, or am I mission something?

Comment: You're right, but if you want to get out of China ASAP, it'll get thr job done.